# How do I use sections with three levels of inheritance

Tags: java, web, template-engine, rythm

I'm using [Rythm](http://rythmengine.org/) as my template engine in Java and I'm trying to use sections with inheritance but I'm stuck with when extending templates more than once.

What I want is to append to a section from more than one place.

**Description:** I have three templates and they inherit as follows:
`base.html < internal.html < main.html` (main being the most specific)

In base.html I have defined a

```
@render(styles) {
  <link href="/ex1.css"/>
}
```

In main.html I include a section as follows:

```
@section(styles) {
  @inherited()
  <link href="/ex3.css">
}
```

So far this works correctly.

**Problem:** When I include a section block in internal.html. (The template in the middle of the hierarchy.)

```
@section(styles) {
  @inherited()
  <link href="/ex2.css">
}
```

The section of internal.html is completely skipped.
Am I doing something wrong or is there a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open an issue at https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm/issues. Before the issue is confirmed and resolved, try to name your internal style with a different section name:

```
@section(internal_section) {
<link href="/ex2.css">
}
```

And in your `base.html` you have

```
@render(styles) {
   @render(internal_section)
   <link href="/ex1.css"/>
}
```